# for in ES6 vs for loop in FizzBuzz test

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an issue understanding why the for in statement in ES6 behaves differently when iterating through an array while doing a simple FizzBuzz test, consider the following example

```
let numbers  = [0,1,2,3,4];
```

Now let us loop through the array with a for loop

```
for (var i=1; i <= numbers.length; i++)
{
    if (i % 15 == 0)
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    else if (i % 3 == 0)
        console.log("Fizz");
    else if (i % 5 == 0)
        console.log("Buzz");
    else
        console.log(i);
}
```

The result is

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
```

Now let us use for in statement in ES6

```
for (number in numbers)
{
    if (number % 15 == 0)
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    else if (number % 3 == 0)
        console.log("Fizz");
    else if (number % 5 == 0)
        console.log("Buzz");
    else
        console.log(number);
}
```

The result is

```
FizzBuzz
1
2
Fizz
4
```

Shouldn't the for in statement behave the same way a for loop?

Comment: No `for..of` loop appears at Question

Comment: @guest271314 edited the question to reflect the issue thanks

Comment: `for..in` loop iterates properties of objects, properties of objects are strings. Again, no `for..of` loop appears at JavaScript at text of Question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that in the first example you're starting i at 1 and testing against i, but in the second loop you're testing against the number in the array, starting from 0.

However, this may not work as expected, depending on your javascript engine. You should not use `for-in` loops to iterate over an array, at all. Opt for this pattern instead:

```
for (let number of numbers) {
  console.log(number);
}
```

This post does a good job of explaining why: https://www.eventbrite.com/engineering/learning-es6-for-of-loop/

Comment: Where is an "ES6 loop" at JavaScript at Question?

Comment: I think this was referring to the `for ... in` loop

Comment: @csander the intention was for ... in

Comment: `value` is not defined at Answer. Where does OP actually use a `for..of` loop at JavaScript at Question?